# Double factorial in assembly for MIPS

Tags: mips

I need to write a MIPS recursive function for:

```
int factorial(int n){
if(n<=1) return 1;
else return n*(n-2)!!
}
```

n is stored in argument register $a0

Is this possible way to do it?

```
factorial: subi $sp, $sp, 8
sw $ra, 4($sp)
sw $a0, 0($sp)
slt $t0, $a0, 1
BEQ $t0, $zero, L1 ; n>1 goto L1
addi $v0, $zero, 1
add $sp, $sp, 8
JR $ra
L1: subi $a0, $a0, 2
jal factorial
lw $a0, 0($sp)
lw $ra, 4($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 8
mult $v0,$a0,$v0
JR $ra
```

Comment: What do you mean is this a way to do it? Did you run it? Did it work? Question answered.

Comment: @KonradLindenbach
Actually i need this to test for college, and we do it on paper.. so i thought if this is wrong and someone has solved it to post it..

Comment: Just because you have to submit it on paper doesn't mean you can't check it on your computer.